# How to extract a .dmg file in Linux?

Tags: linux, extract, dmg-image

As a Linux user, I need to get the content of a .dmg (Mac OSX disk image) file which contains an application installer.

I tried `dmg2dir` (which requires `dmg2img`) which created an .img file but nothing else.

```
$ sudo dmg2dir jdk-8u51-macosx-x64.dmg
==> Routines successfully accomplished. Ready! 
==> Prepare loop device... 
==> Mount block device... 
Error looking up object for device /dev/disk/by-label/JDK\x208\x20Update\x2051 INTENSO openSUSE\x20Live\x20CD\x20GNOME dump
Variable is empty.
```

I just need the files from the .dmg file unpacked, I don't want to mount it.

In case you're curious, I need this to create a portable development environment to be used at workshops on computers that can't be prepared upfront.

Comment: It is a disk image. Unless someone has gone to all the work (which I guess 7z did) to write file system readers into their program, the easiest way is to use the Linux kernel filesystem modules to read the data. Which means mounting it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Just use `7z x`.

In the case of for example Sublime text, `7z x "Sublime Text 2.0.2.dmg"` will be enough to extract all the files.

In other cases, like for example the JDK, you have to deal with some kind of matryoshka.

```
$ 7z x jdk-8u51-macosx-x64.dmg
$ cd JDK 8 Update 51/
$ 7z x JDK 8 Update 51.pkg
$ 7z x Payload~
```

But eventually you will get a folder containing the files you're looking for.

Comment: Extracting dmg files with 7z seem to miss the executable bits, making extracted applications from DMGs dysfunctional. May be related: https://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/bugs/113/

Comment: I get `Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [Dmg] archive`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes 7z do not work correctly.

Use https://sourceforge.net/projects/catacombae/files/HFSExplorer/0.23.1/ for that cases

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac, if the dmg is an image of a directory containing all the files, then make a tgz of the directory instead of a dmg, and migrate it.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d "$1" ]; then  # $1 is the directory name
tar -cf "$1.tar" "$1" || exit  # First, create a tar-file
gzip -n -S .gz "$1.tar"  # Then ,gzip it to compress it.
mv "$1.tar.gz" "$1.tgz"  # Then rename it ti a .tgz
echo "Created $PWD/$1.tgz"
else echo "Not a directory"
fi
exit 0
```